# How do I check if the members of a json array is empty, in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm terribly new to javascript and I tried to foreach through members of an array to see if they are empty, but couldn't quite figure out how to do it, I've tried several ways already.

So here is the json array:

```
var myArray = {
                a:document.getElementById('id').value,
                b:document.getElementById('password').value,

            };
```

and here is my attempt at checking if respective members of that array is empty:

```
for (var check in myArray) {
                if((check == null)||(check.length===0)||(check=='')){
                    console.log("empty member found!");
                    break;
                    }else{console.log(check);}
               }
```

as it turned out it passes the check every time and when it prints out check, it prints out only a, b in the browser console, not its value as I had expected.

I know I must've made several entry-level mistake but how should I fix it?

Comment: `for..in` gives you the *keys*, not the values. Either use `myArray[check]` or use `for..of` instead. (or `Object.values`)

Comment: Fixed... for now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So as  CertainPerformance pointed out, you can't really use:

```
if((check == null)||(check.length===0)||(check==''))
```

instead, I used:

```
if((emptyCheckArray[check] == null)||(emptyCheckArray[check].length===0)||(emptyCheckArray[check]==''))
```

and it did the trick! Note that my code may be redundant, but hey, safe > sorry!

Comment: if(emptyCheckArray[check]) would be enough in this case. Also you kinda have the empty string checked twice (length === 0 and string == '').

Comment: "emptyCheckArray" clearly is a library function. I'm new to js, what library am I using by invoking that method?

Comment: It is not a function. Probably the array containing values to check for emptiness. Just add ;console.log(emptyCheckArray); and you will see in the console what it is.